# NPM install package: GeoFireX, error with google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to install [GeoFireX](https://github.com/codediodeio/geofirex).

I did this steps like the documentation said:

```
npm install geofirex
# peer dependencies
npm install rxjs firebase
```

But when I install the packages I get this message:

```
npm WARN geofirex@0.0.6 requires a peer of firebase@5.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So I tried installing firebase@5.2.0, but the message keeps coming.

I'm using the code for a google cloud function in typescript:

```
export const functionName = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=>{
      const point = geo.point(40, -119);

      await admin.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc')
      .update({'position': point.data});
      res.send(200);
});
```

The logs of Firebase give this error:

```
at GeoFirePoint.get [as geoPoint] (/srv/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1390:43)
    at GeoFirePoint.get [as data] (/srv/node_modules/geofirex/dist/index.cjs.js:1411:32)
    at exports.bgLocation.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/lib/index.js:590:101)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your npm version

Comment: Where can I find that? I installed the package npm check...

Comment: npm -v for version

Comment: Did you solve the error or its still there?

Comment: The error is still there...